# IOS app cannot get Facebook uid by calling me() in FQL

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm writing a program for IOS and want to get uid and name of the current user. I tried me(), but it does not return any value:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

However it works when the uid is known, for example:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid = 4
```

Does me() require permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'me()' shortcut should work in any FQL query you make with a user's access token

If this isn't working you may not actually be operating with a logged-in user - many API calls will still work without a user login

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it does require permission. You need to have the user authorize your app before the /me endpoint will work.